# Complexity formula of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have this algorithm (golden ratio):

```
public static float golden(int n){

float res;

if(n == 0) {
  res = 1;
} else {
  res = (float) (1.0 + (1.0 / golden(n-1)));
}
return res;

}
```

I suppose The T(n) formula is **T(n-1)**. I can get the complexity following this formula.

**T(n) = aT(n - b) + c^n p(n)**

and this one:

[image: click]

**What's p(n) and c?**

Comment: Here's a hint: could you implement this *without* recursion? What's the complexity now?

Comment: I have only "studied" recursive formulas, so I have no idea... And the answer must be as a recursive formula too. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Your `golden` function has `O(n)` complexity, since each call takes constant time + calling `golden(n-1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each *n > 0* the call to `golden(n)` results in a constant number of arithmetic operations and one recursive call, therefore you can write the recurrence for the time complexity function *T(n)* as

*T(n) = T(n-1) + k, n>0*

where *k* is the number of operations in each call. This is the recurrence relation for sequential search.

Now you can apply the formula that you mention in the question. Recall that *d* in the formula is the degree of the polynomial *p(n)*. Here

*a = 1, c = 1, b = 1, and p(n) = k,*

therefore *d = 0*, now applying your formula you get *a=c^b*, and therefore the second case applies, so

*T(n) = Theta(n^{d+1}c^n) = Theta(n)*.

This gives the final answer **T(n) = Theta(n)**.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you recommend me any good book about this subject?

Comment: @ErJasin Have a look at the 2nd and 3rd chapters of "Introduction to Algorithms"  by T.H. Cormen, C.E. Leiserson, R.L. Rivest and C. Stein. I do not know a book where you can find the formula you mentioned in the post, but it is not hard to prove using just the formula for geometric series sum.